# Why isnt my sockets onsubscribe event getting used?

Tags: spring-boot, sockets, websocket, spring-websocket, stomp

I am using java springboot with maven in order to get the spring boot starter socket package. My clients are using angular with stompjs and sockjs-client.
I am trying to set up a simple web socket application that allows for multiple rooms based on a roomId. When a client joins a room they should receive the last five messages sent in that room.

My Springboot app has three classes, the basic Application.java that I use to run the app, a web socket config class and a web socket controller:

```java
@Controller
public class WebSocketController {
    private final SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    WebSocketController(SimpMessagingTemplate template){
        this.template = template;
    }

    @MessageMapping("/meeting/{roomId}")
    private void sendMessageTpPrivateRoom(
            String message, 
            @DestinationVariable String roomId
    ) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("message sent to: " + roomId);
        this.template.convertAndSend("/meeting/" + roomId, message);
        addToHistory(roomId, message);
    }

    @SubscribeMapping("/meeting/{roomId}")
    public String chatInit(@DestinationVariable String roomId) {
        System.out.println("Someone joined room: " + roomId);
        return getLastFiveMessages(roomId);
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration
        extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/socket")
                .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                .withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
                .enableSimpleBroker("/meeting");
    }
}
```

my clients are subscribing to the socket like so:

```java
stompClient.subscribe(`app/meeting/${roomId}`, (message) => {
    if (message.body) {
        console.log(message.body);
        messages += '<br>' + message.body;
    }
});
```

and sending messages like so:

```java
this.stompClient.send(`/app/meeting/${this.roomId}` , {}, message);
```

The message sending and handling is working great, when I set up three clients, two in room one, and one in room two, the room two messages are not being seen in room one and the room one messages are seen by both clients.

However the on subscribe event is not firing no matter what room I join. It is very necessary that when a client joins room one, they should receive some sort of history of that room. **Any advice as to why my SubscribeMapping method is not being triggered when a client subscribes to the room?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/meeting` part will be implicitly added to URL you provide when subscribing. So your mapping will look like this:

```
    @SubscribeMapping("/${roomId}")
    public String chatInit(@DestinationVariable String roomId) {
        System.out.println("Someone joined room: " + roomId);
        return getLastFiveMessages(roomId);
    }
```

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html

Comment: so it turns out that actually I just needed to prepend the subscription path with 'app' so the full path was 'app/meeting/roomId'. Now when I join the room I get my message! But now there is an issue where I subscribe to app/meeting/roomId but when I send messages since I am no longer subscribed to regular /meeting/roomId it seems that I am no longer receiving the messages I am sending. The only response I get is from the subscribeMapping and I assume that is because it is no longer going through the broker. Any idea how to get the broker to send to app/meeting/roomId? Updated above to reflect

Comment: It seems as though the expectation would be that each client needs to subscribe to app/meeting/roomId AND /meeting/roomId in order to get the subscription response as well as all future messages?